# Add to each other

Tags: unrealscript

The old `UE3` is used, which still supports `UnrealScript`.
So, the question is, is it possible to dynamically add elements to each other?
Like this in `Unity`:

```
NewObject.transform.SetParent(Object, false);
```

How can this be done in `UnrealScript`?
It's through the code.

I can't find any information.